# How can I add item to the top ActionBar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I would like to add new icon to the top action bar, bet instead of adding to the top, the icon appear on the bottom of the screen. How can I add item to the top ActionBar?

XML:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">    
    <item android:id="@+id/preferences"
        android:icon="@drawable/preferences"    
        android:title="Preferences"
        android:showAsAction="always|withText"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/help"
        android:title="Help"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search" />    
</menu>
```

Java:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_ygo_main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: on a side note, id advise you to try out actionbarsherlock (http://actionbarsherlock.com/). it'll probably accomplish what you're doing, and provide backward compatibility with versions before 3.0

Comment: Which Android/SDK version do you use? And what do you mean by "on the bottom" in the classic options menu or is there an actionbar on the bottom.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Taken from http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#SplitBar

> To enable split action bar, simply add
>   uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" to your  or
>    manifest element.

So if you want to have an item in the top. Make sure that this line is NOT in your code.

Comment: But from the above explanation, shouldn't the result of using android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" be, that the action bar shows part at the top and the rest at the bottom? In my case using that attribute causes the upper actionbar to be empty and the lower one to be filled with my actions. This doesn't seem right? P.s. I am using actionbarsherlock on a Galaxy SII with API Level 10.

Comment: Try filling your actionbar with more actions and see if they come up to the top just to test. Alternatively, there should be some "showAsAction" settings that will help you bring it up to the top.

Comment: Actually I have three actions (just text, no icons) and sometimes (the icon titles change dynamically) only two of them are visible, the third apparently slides off the bottom bar and is gone for good ;) . In my menu declaration I defined all actionbar actions as  android:showAsAction="always" but it doesn't really help... However, if I switch my actionbar to NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST and use a navigation list plus two actions, then the navigation list is displayed at the top bar, the other two at the bottom (as it should be).

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" in the activity definition in your AndroidManifest.xml. That's what makes action bar split to the bottom.

Check ActionBarSherlock for what you are doing. It will provide ActionBar functionality on the older android versions and will use native ActionBar when it's supported. It has sample application showcasing most of its settings http://actionbarsherlock.com/index.html

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the bar to split, give that icon more space, for example removing 'withText' or shortening the title on the bar, and adding 'ifRoom' in showAsAction parameter.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"  

     >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.androidactionbarbottam.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

This is main line in mani feast u should do this to solve ur problem

android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"

Comment: u can also add there text or image at bottom